# Loop in shell script not working on remote server

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

The code tries to ssh from my local server to remote server and runs some commands.

```
ssh root@$remoteip 'bash -s' <<END3               
gcdadirs=`strings binary | egrep '.gcda$'`       
for dir in ${gcdadirs[@]}; do
directory=$(dirname ${dir})
echo $dir >> dirstr.txt
mkdir -p $directory
chown $root:$root $directory
chmod 777 $directory
done
END3
```

the above creates a directory structure on remote server which is working fine.

I want to tar up the same directory structure. so i'm using same logic as above.

```
ssh root@$remoteip 'bash -s' <<END3   
touch emptyfile
tar -cf gcda.tar emptyfile
gcdadirs=`strings binary | egrep '.gcda$'`
for dir in ${gcdadirs[@]}; do
tar -rf gcda.tar $dir
done
END3
```

The above piece of code should create a tar with all the directories included returned by for loop. i tried the code logic by copying the code to remote server and running it there and it worked. But if I ssh connect from my local server to remote server and try it is not enetring the for loop. it is not appending anything to tar file created with empty file in second line.

Comment: Try making a bash script for what you are trying to execute remotely, then pipe it to ssh. `ssh root@$remoteip 'bash -s' < scriptname`. I think it might have to do with how the here document is processed.

Comment: or try `<<'END3'` (note the quotes around END3). Good luck.

Comment: I'm surprised the first example worked, because without quoting the delimiter for the here document, all substitutions should happen locally.  It might have worked if the OP tested his code locally and thus still had the environment variables set

Comment: You can also put everything in a script, copy that script to the remote server and call it from the remote server.

Comment: @WalterA I wanted everything in a single script.. if nothing works, probably I'll do that. thanks.

Comment: @ex-bart what difference do the quotes around END3 do ? thanks

Comment: @Shashank They prevent shell substitutions inside the [here-document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).  You want the `$`-signs to be transferred to the other side of the ssh connection, not interpreted locally.  Same for the backticks.

Comment: @shelter it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try <<'END3'

Note the quotes around END3, they prevent shell substitutions inside the here-document. You want the $-signs to be transferred to the other side of the ssh connection, not interpreted locally. Same for the backticks.

---

Extracted from the comments as the accepted answer. Posting as community wiki